# Grouping WSAPI data store by Parent Name

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I am creating a `rallygrid` component and would like to have the grid items grouped by their parent's `Name` attribute (bonus if I could also display the ID of the parent). I added the `groupBy:'Parent'` configuration to the `storeConfig` of the grid and was surprised that no results were returned. I also tried using `groupBy:'Parent.Name'` but still nothing.

I know this is possible with other fields such as Owner, but I'm at a loss as to why the Parent wouldn't be usable as well. Is this a bug, or am I setting the config up incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `storeConfig` to keep the records from trying to update after being grouped:

```
storeConfig : {
    remoteSort   : false,
    remoteGroup  : false,
    remoteFilter : false,
}
```

Add a listener to the `load` event which assigns a root level property to the record and groups by that record value. (For some reason `store.group('Parent.Name');` doesn't work.)

```
load: function(store) {
    store.each(function(record) {
        record.set('ParentName', record.get('Parent') && record.get('Parent').Name || '-- Unparented --');
    });

    store.group('ParentName');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was a  bug with the SDK too, but per [WS API documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/), Parent, unlike Owner, or Feature is not sortable.

So when I use `groupField: 'Parent'` the grid is empty, and response showed error:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.callback6({"QueryResult": {..., "Errors": ["Cannot sort using attribute Parent"]
```

It is trying to sort by Parent, but Parent attribute is not sortable. So the SDK ran into a WS API limitation.

On a side note, I did not use `groupBy`, instead I used `groupField` on the store ([in this example](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/child-stories-grouped-by-kanban) I grouped by Kanban field) :

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore',{
        model: 'UserStory',
        groupField: 'c_MyKB',
        //...
    });
```

And then used features: `[{ftype:'grouping'}]` in the grid.

```
this._myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: myStore,
        features: [{ftype:'grouping'}],
                //...
```

Comment: That was a typo on my part, I used "groupField" as well. I ended up solving this issue by grouping the store after it had been loaded, rather than trying to group on your end. I'll post my solution...